# Proper and right way to access and then close all Database connections in Android

Tags: android, mysql, database

I have many databases in a single app, each is used for a specific reason and sometimes I use more than one in a single activity. For an example, in this activity, let's call it `Activity A`, I define three databases.

```
DatabaseHandler highscoreDB, db, settingsDB;
```

and then in the `onCreate`, I call

```
settingsDB = new DatabaseHandler(this, "settings");
db = new DatabaseHandler(this, "db");
highscoreDB = new DatabaseHandler(this, "highscore");
```

I
use each separately, like, I may add a new item or update the item by accessing the database.

```
        highscoreDB.addContact(new Contact("Highscore", 0));
```

etc..., depending on my needs. **My question is**, is this a right way to access and create databases?

Then, I started getting crashes when I change the activity, so I looked it up, and I think it is because I dont close my database connections, so I did this in my back button press.

```
db.close();
highscoreDB.close();
settingsDB.close();
this.finish();
Intent i = new Intent(MainnActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

(**Quesiton 2**) Is this the right way to close the db connections? Also, in my next activity, let us say `Activity B`, if I wanna access a database, I do what I have done before which is `settingsDB = new DatabaseHandler(this, "settings");`, (**Question 3**) is it fine?

---

**Update:**

```
DataBaseHandler.java

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
//    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

    // Contacts table name
    private static String TABLE_NAME = "Data";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context, String DATABASE_NAME) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getDouble(2));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getDouble(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    }

    public boolean updatedetails(long rowId, String name, double num)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_ID, rowId);
        args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        args.put(KEY_PH_NO, num);
        int i =  db.update(TABLE_NAME, args, KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null);
        return i > 0;
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are You using Database Adapters and Database OpenHelpers in your app?

Comment: Let me understand one thing, why are you in need of multiple Databases?, is your true need is for multiple tables inside one database? the link you've provided is showing how to create one database with one table inside. For better working with data inside any application it is advisable to have only one database with as many as you need of tables, indexes, views...

Comment: please submit the code of your databaseOpenHelper and databaseAdapter, I will work with you through creating multiple tables in one db and how you can change them

Comment: @F.sh Okay, thank you very much. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of DatabaseOpenHelper that has one database and 5 tables

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private final static String databaseName = "Menu_DB";
private final static int    databaseVersion = 1;

private final static String CatsTable_Name = "tbl_Cats";
private final static String ItemsTable_Name = "tbl_Items";
private final static String PostsTable_Name = "tbl_Posts";
private final static String ContactsTable_Name = "tbl_Contacts";
private final static String FavoriteTable_Name = "tbl_Favorite";

private final static String Record_ID = "_id";
private final static String Record_URL = "URL";

private final static String Cat_Kind = "Cat_Kind";
private final static String Cat_ID = "Cat_ID";
private final static String Cat_Name_en = "Cat_Name_en";
private final static String Cat_Name_ar = "Cat_Name_ar";
private final static String Cat_Image = "Cat_Image";
private final static String Cat_Order = "Cat_Order";

private final static String Item_ID = "Item_ID";
private final static String Item_Name_en = "Item_Name_en";
private final static String Item_Name_ar = "Item_Name_ar";
private final static String Item_About_en = "Item_About_en";
private final static String Item_About_ar = "Item_About_ar";
private final static String Item_Price_en = "Item_Price_en";
private final static String Item_Price_ar = "Item_Price_ar";
private final static String Item_Currency_en = "Item_Currency_en";
private final static String Item_Currency_ar = "Item_Currency_ar";
private final static String Item_Image = "Item_Image";
private final static String Show_Image = "Show_Image";
private final static String Show_Basket = "Show_Basket";
private final static String Item_Order = "Item_Order";

private final static String Item_Qty = "Item_Qty";

public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, databaseName, null, databaseVersion);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CreateCatsTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + CatsTable_Name + " ("     +
            Record_ID   + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "                          +
            Cat_Kind    + " TEXT, "                                         +
            Cat_ID      + " INTEGER, "                                      +
            Cat_Name_en + " TEXT, "                                         +
            Cat_Name_ar + " TEXT, "                                         +
            Cat_Image   + " TEXT, "                                         +
            Show_Image  + " TEXT, "                                         +
            Cat_Order   + " INTEGER);"                                      ;
    db.execSQL(CreateCatsTableSQL);

    String CreateItemsTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + ItemsTable_Name + " ("   +
            Record_ID           + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "                  +
            Cat_Kind            + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Cat_ID              + " INTEGER, "                              +
            Item_ID             + " INTEGER, "                              +
            Item_Name_en        + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Item_Name_ar        + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Item_About_en       + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Item_About_ar       + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Item_Price_en       + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Item_Price_ar       + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Item_Currency_en    + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Item_Currency_ar    + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Item_Image          + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Show_Image          + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Show_Basket         + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Item_Order          + " INTEGER);"                              ;
    db.execSQL(CreateItemsTableSQL);

    String CreatePostsTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + PostsTable_Name + " ("   +
            Record_ID   + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "                          +
            Record_URL  + " TEXT);"                                         ;
    db.execSQL(CreatePostsTableSQL);

    String CreateContactsTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + ContactsTable_Name + " ("     +
            Record_ID   + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "                                  +
            Record_URL  + " TEXT);"                                                 ;
    db.execSQL(CreateContactsTableSQL);

    String CreateFavoriteTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + FavoriteTable_Name + " ("     +
            Record_ID       + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "                              +
            Item_ID             + " INTEGER, "                              +
            Item_Name_en        + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Item_Name_ar        + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Item_Price_en       + " TEXT, "                                 +
            Item_Qty            + " INTEGER) "                              ;
    db.execSQL(CreateFavoriteTableSQL);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int Old_Version, int New_Version) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CatsTable_Name);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ItemsTable_Name);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PostsTable_Name);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ContactsTable_Name);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FavoriteTable_Name);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

You should create a DatabaseAdapter, this will contain all methods and functions to control your database and tables, here is an example

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private DatabaseOpenHelper dbHelper;

private final static String FavoriteTable_Name = "tbl_Favorite";
private final static String CatsTable_Name = "tbl_Cats";
private final static String ItemsTable_Name = "tbl_Items";

private final static String Item_Name_en = "Item_Name_en";
private final static String Item_Name_ar = "Item_Name_ar";
private final static String Item_Price_en = "Item_Price_en";
private final static String Item_Qty = "Item_Qty";

private final static String Record_ID = "_id";

public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public DatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public DatabaseAdapter openForRead() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (dbHelper != null) {
        dbHelper.close();
    }
}

public long dbCreateCatsRecord(ContentValues contentValue) {
    return db.insert(CatsTable_Name, null, contentValue);
}

public long dbCreateItemsRecord(ContentValues contentValue) {
    return db.insert(ItemsTable_Name, null, contentValue);
}

public Cursor GetCatsTableData(String catKind) {
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT Cat_ID, Cat_Name_en, Cat_Name_ar, Cat_Image, Show_Image FROM tbl_Cats Where Cat_Kind = ? Order By Cat_Order", new String[]{catKind});
}

public Cursor GetCatsImages() {
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT Cat_Name_en, Cat_Image FROM tbl_Cats Where Show_Image = 'True'", new String[]{});
}

public Cursor GetItemsImages() {
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT Item_Name_en, Item_Image FROM tbl_Items Where Show_Image = 'True'", new String[]{});
}

public Cursor GetItemsTableData(String catKind, String catID) {
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_Items Where Cat_Kind = ? AND Cat_ID = ? Order By Item_Order", new String[]{catKind, catID});
}

public void dbCreateFavoriteRecord(int Rec_ID, int Qty) {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_Items Where " + Record_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(Rec_ID)});
    if (!(c.moveToFirst()) || c.getCount() == 0) {
        Log.i("Insert New Favorite", "No Item Found");
    } else {
        c.moveToLast();
        ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
        contentValue.put(Record_ID, GetNewRecordID(FavoriteTable_Name, Record_ID));
        contentValue.put(Item_Name_en, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Item_Name_en")));
        contentValue.put(Item_Name_ar, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Item_Name_ar")));
        contentValue.put(Item_Price_en, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Item_Price_en")));
        contentValue.put(Item_Qty, Qty);
        db.insert(FavoriteTable_Name, null, contentValue);
    }
    c.close();
}

public void dbDeleteFavRecord(String Rec_ID) {
    db.delete(FavoriteTable_Name, "_id=?", new String[]{Rec_ID});
}

public int GetNewRecordID(String Table_Name, String Record_ID) {
    Cursor c = db.query(Table_Name, new String[]{Record_ID}, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (!(c.moveToFirst()) || c.getCount() == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        c.moveToLast();
        int newRecId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Record_ID)) + 1;
        c.close();
        return (newRecId);
    }
}

public Cursor GetTableData(String Table_Name) {
    return db.query(Table_Name, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public int GetTableCount(String TableName) {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Q_QTY FROM " + TableName, null);
    if (!(c.moveToFirst()) || c.getCount() == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        c.moveToLast();
        int Q_QTY = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Q_QTY"));
        c.close();
        return Q_QTY;
    }
}

public void ClearTable(String Table_Name) {
    db.delete(Table_Name, null, null);
}
```

}

How would you access the methods in DatabaseAdapter from your activity(s):

Insert Data in a table:

```
ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
    DatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(context);
    databaseAdapter.open();
    contentValue.put("_id", databaseAdapter.GetNewRecordID("tbl_Cats", "_id"));
    contentValue.put("Cat_Kind", iCat_Kind);
    contentValue.put("Cat_ID", Integer.parseInt(iCat_ID));
    contentValue.put("Cat_Name_en", iCat_Name_en);
    contentValue.put("Cat_Name_ar", iCat_Name_ar);
    contentValue.put("Cat_Image", iCat_Image);
    contentValue.put("Show_Image", iShow_Image);
    contentValue.put("Cat_Order", Integer.parseInt(iCat_Order));
    databaseAdapter.dbCreateCatsRecord(contentValue);
    databaseAdapter.close();
```

Here how you can retrieve data from a table

```
            DatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
            databaseAdapter.openForRead();

            //Get Cats Images
            Cursor c = databaseAdapter.GetCatsImages();
            if (c.moveToFirst())
                do {
                    publishProgress("Image for " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Cat_Name_en")));
                    DownLoadImage(ImagePath, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Cat_Image")));
                } while (c.moveToNext());

            //Get Item Images
            c = databaseAdapter.GetItemsImages();
            if (c.moveToFirst())
                do {
                    publishProgress("Image for " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Item_Name_en")));
                    DownLoadImage(ImagePath, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Item_Image")));
                } while (c.moveToNext());

            c.close();
            databaseAdapter.close();
```

In Summary:

- Use One Database.
- Use DatabaseOpenHelper to declare your Database and Tables
- Use DatabaseAdapter to Insert, Update, Clear and retrieve data from tables

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You had better create a SqliteOpenHelper and close the connection by calling helper.close();

Comment: Yes I do have it. I believe it is the same as, db.close();